# Split a string around multiple char sequences

Tags: java, string, split

How can I split a string in Java using multiple delimiters extracted from the input string? (the delimiters are inside the square brackets, and they can be two or more):

```
"//[delim1][delim2]\n"
```

I tried this:

```
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        String[] delimiters;
        int c=0;
        while (m.find() and c<counter) { //counter is a number of occurences of square brackets
            delimiters[c] = m.group(1);
            c++;
        }
        nums = s.split(delimiters));
```

But apparently split doesn't take an array of strings as argument

For example, if I take the string

```
"//[*][%]\n1*2%3"
```

i should consider only the substring after \n, and it should return numbers 1, 2 and 3

Comment: You can pass a regex to split.  Is the question what regex will match those delims?

Comment: You can define a class of delimiters for example `str.split("[,_ ]")` which will split with `,` or `_` or `space`

Comment: beside can you show us some input and the expected outputs + what you tried before please?

Comment: ok, updated the question

Comment: You still haven't provided sample input and expected output.

Comment: updated again, hope it's more clear

Answer (score 1):

The parameter for method `split` in class `java.lang.String` is a regular expression. The method documentation in Java 8 is here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-

Provide a sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example for you using String's [split()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-string-java-examples/) with a regex offering three delimiters (digit, whitespace, literal question mark):

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "foo stack3overflow bar?regex\njava";
        String[] arr = str.split("(\\d|\\s|\\?)");
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[foo, stack, overflow, bar, regex, java]
```

Here's another example where you can choose the delimiters dynamically. The catch is that the delimiters need to result in a valid regex, so I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for. It's almost certainly not reliable/useful as a public method.

Alternatives are splitting repeatedly on non-regex patterns (potentially slow) or rolling your own `split` that iterates and chops on non-regex (potentially bug prone).

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] delimiters = {" ", "\n", "\\?", "\\d"};
        String str = "foo stack3overflow bar?regex\njava";
        String pattern = "(" + String.join("|", delimiters) + ")";
        String[] arr = str.split(pattern);
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[foo, stack, overflow, bar, regex, java]
```

**Update**: looking at your example input (`"//[*][%]\n1*2%3"`), code, and desired output: `[1, 2, 3]`, how about something like:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "//[*][%]\n1*2%3";
        String pattern = "\\d";

        ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(str);

        while (m.find()) {
           matches.add(m.group());
        }

        System.out.println(matches.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that i should extract delimiters from a specific input string, they are not standard

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to iterate over a list of delimiters:

```
class Ocl {
  public static ArrayList<String> split(String str, List<String> delimiters)
  { if (0 < delimiters.size()) 
    { String delim = delimiters.get(0); 
      List<String> taildelims = Ocl.tail(delimiters); 

      String[] splits = str.split(delim);
   
      ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>(); 
      for (int j = 0; j < splits.length; j++) 
      { res.addAll(Ocl.split(splits[j], taildelims)); }
      return res; 
    }
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    result.add(str); 
    return result; 
  }
}

public static <T> ArrayList<T> tail(List<T> a)
{ ArrayList<T> res = new ArrayList<T>(); 
  for (int i = 1; i < a.size(); i++)
  { res.add(a.get(i)); } 
  return res; 
}
```